# How do i compile .py to a .exe?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, py2exe

I am trying to compile my .py script into a .exe using py2exe using this code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(
options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2}},
windows = [{'script': "get.py"}],
zipfile = "shared.lib",
)
```

I get this in my console:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
creating python loader for extension 'unicodedata' (C:\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> unicodedata.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'select' (C:\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd -> select.pyd)
creating python loader for extension '_hashlib' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -> _hashlib.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'bz2' (C:\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> bz2.pyd)
*** finding dlls needed ***
*** create binaries ***
*** byte compile python files ***
writing byte-compilation script 'c:\docume~1\user\locals~1\temp\tmpduooti.py'
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe -OO c:\docume~1\user\locals~1\temp\tmpduooti.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\.minecraft\saves\HuFAdventure\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    zipfile = "shared.lib",
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
    raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)
SystemExit: error: command 'C:\Python27\pythonw.exe' failed with exit status 1
>>>
```

Could you please help.

Comment: What's that `zipfile = "shared.lib"` for? What happens if you try without that?

Comment: You could try an alternative such as cx_Freeze (http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @GregHewgill if i remove that line it gives me the same error

Comment: I see. The reason I mentioned that was that line was part of the stack trace in the error you posted. It must be some other problem then.

Comment: ...out of curiosity, why are you creating your python script in the `.minecraft/saves` folder? o.O

Comment: @Amber Oh ^^ I'm making a small script to edit the Minecraft level.dat file.

Comment: You might want to try moving your script to a separate directory and compiling it into an EXE there, then - miscellaneous files in the Minecraft save directory might be interfering with the process.

Comment: Nevermind guys got it to work by removing "options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2}},"

Comment: @Duncan: then put that as the answer and accept it.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan says I can't yet "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: Wow, SO sure has some byzantine rules for new users these days. :)

Comment: The code works perfectly in win7 64bits with py2exe-0.6-10dev and python 2.6.6. Functional executables are produced with no modification of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you intentionally building a gui based script?  If not change `windows = [{'script': "get.py"}],` to `console = ["get.py"],`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2}},
    console = ["get.py"],
    zipfile = "shared.lib",
)
```

If you are building a windowed program then ignore this and leave a comment so I can delete this answer ).